# Can I assign class variables from inside a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I quite obviously don't understand this so could someone tell me why my class variables aren't assigning, and what I could do to make it work? I have two class variables which are array lists.

`listOfPMDFilesInRootZip`  
and  `listOfXMLFilesInRootZip`

**I've cut down plenty of the code so you can just see what matters:**

```
public void parseZip(final Object syncToken) {
    showLoadingAlertDialogue(true);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (syncToken) {
                try {

                      // they're assigned here
                    listOfPMDFilesInRootZip = rootZip.getAllPMDFiles();
                    listOfXMLFilesInRootZip = rootZip.getAllXMLFiles();
                      //  System.out.println(listOfPMDFilesInRootZip.size());
                      //  gives what is expected

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            showLoadingAlertDialogue(false);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

When i'm in the thread and I do`System.out.println(listOfPMDFilesInRootZip.size());` it gives me the expected amount, but when I try access it after the thread has finished, I get a null pointer. So again, could someone tell me why my class variables aren't assigning, and what I could do to make it work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you access it outside the thread?

Comment: Yes, you can but then the variable must be `static`

Comment: Just a tip: You should use AsynkTask to update the ui

Comment: Also check that you don't accidentally shadow those fields with local variables (you don't in the code above, but I don't know is it all the code where you write them, and it does not show the reading part at all).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. @A.S.  I just noticed that I was accessing it before it was initialised like an idiot.. Thanks for pointing me to it. Ispas I'll have a look after i've got one method working. kiheru thanks, this has happened to me a few times since moving to android stuff (there doesn't seem to be any big warning when this happens like in iOS!)

Comment: @Ben : What do you mean by "class" variables? What type of "class"?

Comment: I just meant variables within the class, rather than in the scope of a method. Is there a better name? I have this problem solved now, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ben : What does your "class" extend? Or is it a POJO?

Comment: Just a plain object Squonk. Why are you putting class in quotes? Haha, are you suspicious of it not being a class?

Comment: @Ben : I put class in quotes because very many Android questions here on Stack Overflow use the generic term "class" when the OP is actually referring to an Android `Activity` or `Service`. Interacting with either of those Android class types from a separate thread can introduce problems. I simply wanted to ascertain what you meant. If you had referred to it as a POJO then I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Was just kidding anyway ;) Thanks for the help regardless :P